# C# AWS Lambda Function - Could not find the specified handler assembly with the file name 'LambdaTest, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a "Hello, World" AWS Lambda function, with one minor change: I need to deploy it using a .zip file. In an effort to accomplish this, I've done the following:

**From the Terminal Window**

1. Initialized a new AWS Lambda function using `dotnet new lambda.EmptyFunction --name myFirstFunction --profile default --region us-east-1`
2. `cd` into `myFirstFunction`
3. Run `dotnet publish ./src/myFirstFunction/myFirstFunction.csproj`
4. Navigate into `./src/myFirstFunction/bin/Debug/net6.0/publish`
5. Compress all of the files into a single file named `Archive.zip`.

**From AWS Console in the Browser**

1. Navigate to the `myFirstFunction` Lambda function.
2. Click "Upload from -> .zip file" in the "Code Source" section
3. Choose `Archive.zip`
4. Navigate to the "test" tab once successfully uploaded
5. Click the "Test" button in the "Test event" section

At this point, I receive an error that says:

```
{
  "errorType": "LambdaValidationException",
  "errorMessage": "Could not find the specified handler assembly with the file name 'LambdaTest, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The assembly should be located in the root of your uploaded .zip file.",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.UserCodeLoader.Init(Action`1 customerLoggingAction) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeLoader.cs:line 95",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.UserCodeInitializer.InitializeAsync() in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeInitializer.cs:line 46",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.LambdaBootstrap.InitializeAsync() in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/LambdaBootstrap.cs:line 155"
  ]
}
```

I'm unsure how to fix this. I do not see "LambdaTest" in any of the config files. So, I have no idea where that identifier is coming from. What do I need to do to get this based Lambda function working via the "test" tab in the AWS Console?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What happens is that AWS is not able to indentify where your function handler is.

When you create a Lambda in AWS, by default it assigns a LambdaTest handler.

During the deployment of your Lambda code, you need to ensure you are deploying a correct handler for your function.

I could be more helpful if I knew your code and the solution structure, but lets give a try.

Under `/src/myFirstFunction` you might have a file called `aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json`. In that file, there will be a key `"function-handler"` and the value should point to your function handler, in the format: `<project_name>::<namespace>.<class>::<method_name>`

Imagine you have:

```
namespace Farm
{
    public class Banana
    {
        public string Harvest(string season, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            ...
        }
    } 
}
```

Your handler should be **`myFirstFunction::Farm.Banana::Harvest`**

More info on: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-creating-project-in-visual-studio.html

---

If you not using Visual Studio:

- Access AWS Management Console;
- Navigate to your Lambda function `myFirstFunction`;
- Under the **Code** tab, you will see the **Runtime settings**. Press **Edit**;
- Change the handler name according to the format I mentioned above (`<project_name>::<namespace>.<class>::<method_name>`);
- Save and test

Comment: This helped me a ton! If you are using Visual Studio and the Mock Lambda Test Tools you can look at the serverless.template file and the value will be in there too

Comment: @Fabio Absolutely brilliant explanation. Simple, clear, and to the point.